# ActiveRecord user-supplied column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to allow the end-user of a rails app to limit results based on the value of an arbitrary column. At its simplest, I want to do something roughly equivalent to:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE (#{params[:min_col]} >= #{params[:min]})"
```

without the injection vulnerability.

For example, `example.com/myapp/catalog?min_col=sell_price&min=300` would return all products with sell_price greater than or equal to $3.00

I tried adding a scope like this to the model:

```
->(column,min) { where("? >= ?", column, min) }
```

and passing the uri parameters to that scope, but this yields

```
WHERE ('sell_price' >= '300')
```

which seems to just be comparing two literal strings -- this query and others like it always return every row or no rows. How do I get the desired behavior of comparing against a column specified in `params`?

Comment: Rails v. 3.2.16
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I think ransack will help you here. Read the docs and give it a try. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: @user3678068's solution is about the best you will do.  The validation of the column taken from parameters is essential to prevent SQL injection attacks.  The `?` escape will always convert the Ruby type into the corresponding SQL type. Ergo the quotes for strings.  I thought a symbol might work but tried and found it does not.  You get the quotes for the symbol as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent sql injection, you should validate the column is a valid one

```
valid_cols = ["c1", "c2"]
valid_cols.include?(column) or raise "Bad query"
```

Then you can just use the query interface as before

```
Model.where("#{column} >= ?", min)
```

Comment: You can [#column_names](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-column_names) to determine if the column is valid, ie. `Model.column_names.include? params[:min_col]` instead of duplicating the column list as shown above.

Comment: good advice, but sometimes you may not want to expose all fields